# Integral that is continuous and looks like it converges to a geometric series

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

[image]

I think the key word is continous. the RHS totally looks like a sum from a geometric series but I dont see a trick when I think there is one .

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $g(x) = (x+1)^{2017}$. Let $h = f-g$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $a$ such that
$$h(a) = \int_0^1 h(x) \, dx.$$